# 3-dimensional dataset to test tri-clustering method

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am looking for a 3-dimensional valued dataset to test my tri-clustering method. 
I hope to find something like a movie rating database with dimensions for user-movie-genre and ratings depending on both movie and genre (e.g. user rates the movie as a 5-star horror, 3-star thriller, or 1-star comedy).

Any fields will do. Only the structure of the data is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start looking for datasets is the [Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) from UCI.

There are a few datasets that stand out for your method. Although they may not match exactly, you may get some ideas.

- [The YouTube Codedy Slam Preference Data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/YouTube+Comedy+Slam+Preference+Data)
- [Character Trajectories](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Character+Trajectories)
- [User Identification from Walking Activity](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/User+Identification+From+Walking+Activity)

You can use the table columns "Default Task", "Attribute Types", and "# Attributes" to help narrow down more possible data sets.

Comment: For the UCI datasets, here is the link to the clustering datasets: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=clu&att=&area=&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table

Answer (score 1):

You can find clustering datasets that are publicly available by googling. Here are a few  more:

KEEL - http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/datasets.php

ResearchGate Forum / Do you know any free large-scale dataset for clustering? - http://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_you_know_any_free_large-scale_dataset_for_clustering

University of Illinois - Intelligent Data Set - http://uisacad2.uis.edu/dstar/data/clusteringdata.html

University of Koln - http://www.uni-koeln.de/themen/statistik/data/cluster/